# Leaking this in construcor - then java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I've two classes, one that is responsible for "drawing" the graphics interface (MainFrame class) and another one that is a form that should be added to a panel.

When I run the code I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at view.MainFrame2.addModuleToLeftPanel(MainFrame2.java:213)
    at view.modules.PingPong.<init>(PingPong.java:179)
    at view.MainFrame2.<init>(MainFrame2.java:65)
    at view.MainFrame2.<init>(MainFrame2.java:37)
    at view.MainFrame2$3.run(MainFrame2.java:224)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Here is the method in my MainFrame class:

```
public void addModuleToLeftPanel(String tittle, Component module)
{
    leftTabbedPane.add(tittle, module);
}
```

And `leftTabbedPane` is a `JTabbedPane()`

My other class where I call this method from MainFrame is:

```
public PingPong(final Api api, MainFrame2 mainFrame) {

(...)

mainFrame.addModuleToLeftPanel("Test", this); // here I get Leaking this in construcor warning.
}
```

I understand that the null pointer exception is because I'm adding an object that has not been initialized, right? My question is, how can I fix this problem?

What I want is to let PingPong class tell MainFrame "Hey, add me to the left panel" and MainFrame adds PingPong to the left panel.

**----------------------- EDIT ------------------------**

As requested, here is the code from MainFrame2 class and PingPong class:

**MainFrame2.class**:

```
public class MainFrame2 extends JFrame {

    // Classes in this project
    private ToolBar2 toolBar;
    private Api api;
    private StatusPanel2 statusPanel;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    // Modules go here
    private PingPong pingPong;

    // Class variables
    private JTabbedPane leftTabbedPane;
    private JTabbedPane rightTabbedPane;
    private JSplitPane splitPane;

    private MainFrame2() {
        super("An awesome piece of software");



        // Classes Initialization
        api = Api.getInstance();
        toolBar = new ToolBar2(api);
        statusPanel = StatusPanel2.getInstance();

        // Module classes initialization
        pingPong = new PingPong(api, this);

        // Java Imported Classes Initialization
        leftTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        rightTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftTabbedPane, rightTabbedPane);

        // JSplitPanel properties, make is one click expandable.
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);

        // Window properties
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);//start as maximized
        setVisible(true);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        // Do nothing because there is a window closing listener that handles it
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        // Set Layout Manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Rezise the textPanel, otherwise by default it is just one line height
        statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 150));
        statusPanel.revalidate(); //Apply the changes.

        /*
         * To disconnect to the MySQL server when closing
         * the program window
         */
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    api.disconnet();
                    dispose(); //clean garbage collector
                    System.gc(); //clean garbage collector
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });


        // Add the components
        add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Set the Menu
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
    }


    /*
     * *************************************************************
     * ----------------------- Menu Section ------------------------
     * *************************************************************
     */
    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu windowMenu = new JMenu("Window");

        JCheckBoxMenuItem showDataProcessForm = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Show Data Input Panel");

        showDataProcessForm.setSelected(true);

        JMenuItem showSourceServerForm = new JMenuItem("Configure Source Server");
        JMenuItem showDestinationServerForm = new JMenuItem("Configure Destination Server");
        JMenuItem optionsDialogForm = new JMenuItem("Options");

        editMenu.add(showSourceServerForm);
        editMenu.add(showDestinationServerForm);
        editMenu.add(optionsDialogForm);

        windowMenu.add(showDataProcessForm);

        JMenuItem importResults = new JMenuItem("Import Results");
        JMenuItem exportResults = new JMenuItem("Export Results");
        JMenuItem importDatabase = new JMenuItem("Import Table to the Database");
        JMenuItem exportDatabaseTable = new JMenuItem("Export Table from the Database");
        JMenuItem quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");

        fileMenu.add(importResults);
        fileMenu.add(exportResults);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(importDatabase);
        fileMenu.add(exportDatabaseTable);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(quitItem);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(windowMenu);



        // Creating Mnemonics
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);//VK_F stands for virtual key, alt+F
        editMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E); // alt + E
        windowMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_W); // alt + W
//        showSourceServerForm.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S); // alt + s
//        showDestinationServerForm.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D); // alt + d


         // Creating accelerators, control + s -> save file
        quitItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        importResults.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_I, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        exportResults.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        showSourceServerForm.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        showDestinationServerForm.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));




        /*
         * Adding Action Listener
         */
        quitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MainFrame2.this, "Do you really want to quit the application?", "Confirm Exit", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                if (action == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    WindowListener[] listeners = getWindowListeners();

                    for (WindowListener listener : listeners) {
                        listener.windowClosing(new WindowEvent(MainFrame2.this, 0));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return menuBar;
    }

    public void addModuleToLeftPanel(String tittle, Component module)
    {
        leftTabbedPane.add(tittle, module);
    }


    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame2();                
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**PingPong.class:**

```
public class PingPong extends JPanel {

    private JLabel readFromLabel;
    private JLabel accessSessionTimeThresholdLabelLabel;
    private JLabel transitionTimeThresholdLabelLabel;
    private JLabel smoothLabel;
    private JLabel statisticsLabel;

    private JTextField accessSessionTimeThresholdField;
    private JTextField transitionTimeThresholdField;
    private JTextField writeToNewTableField;

    private JComboBox readFromComboBox;
    private JComboBox writeToTableComboBox;

    private JRadioButton writeResultsToNewTableRadio;
    private JRadioButton writeResultsToExistingTableRadio;
    private ButtonGroup writeResultsToTableGroup;

    private JCheckBox smoothCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox statisticsCheckBox;

    private JButton applyButton;
    private JButton refreshReadDataFrom;
    private JButton refreshSaveDataTo;

    private String[] itemsComboBox;

    public PingPong(final Api api, MainFrame2 mainFrame) 
    {
        Border innerBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Detect Ping Pong");
        Border outterBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outterBorder, innerBorder));

        Dimension dim = new Dimension(400, 100);
        setPreferredSize(dim);
        setMinimumSize(dim);

        // Labels
        readFromLabel = new JLabel("Read Data From: ");
        writeResultsToExistingTableRadio = new JRadioButton("Save Results to Existing Table: ");
        writeResultsToNewTableRadio = new JRadioButton("Save Results to New Table: ");
        accessSessionTimeThresholdLabelLabel = new JLabel("Access Session Time Threshold: ");
        transitionTimeThresholdLabelLabel = new JLabel("Transition Time Threshold: ");
        smoothLabel = new JLabel("Smooth Ping Pong?");
        statisticsLabel = new JLabel("Output Ping Pong statistics?");

        // JTextFields
        accessSessionTimeThresholdField = new JTextField(5);
        transitionTimeThresholdField = new JTextField(5);
        writeToNewTableField = new JTextField(10);

        // JCheckBox
        smoothCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        statisticsCheckBox = new JCheckBox();

        itemsComboBox = new String[] {"Not Connected"};
        readFromComboBox = new JComboBox(itemsComboBox);
        writeToTableComboBox = new JComboBox(itemsComboBox);

        // JButton
        applyButton = new JButton("Apply");
        refreshReadDataFrom = new JButton();
        refreshReadDataFrom.setIcon(createIcon("/view/images/view-refresh.png"));
        refreshReadDataFrom.setToolTipText("Refresh the current table list.");
        refreshSaveDataTo = new JButton();
        refreshSaveDataTo.setIcon(createIcon("/view/images/view-refresh.png"));
        refreshSaveDataTo.setToolTipText("Refresh the current table list.");

        writeResultsToTableGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        writeResultsToTableGroup.add(writeResultsToExistingTableRadio);
        writeResultsToTableGroup.add(writeResultsToNewTableRadio);


        // Adding a listener to the Apply JButton
        applyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Get the database table to where save the results
                String writeToTable = "";                
                String sessionThreshold = accessSessionTimeThresholdField.getText();
                String transitionThreshold = transitionTimeThresholdField.getText();
                String readFromTable = readFromComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                boolean smoothPingPong = smoothCheckBox.isSelected();
                boolean statistics = smoothCheckBox.isSelected();
                boolean newTable = writeResultsToNewTableRadio.isSelected();

                if(writeResultsToExistingTableRadio.isSelected())
                {
                    writeToTable = writeToTableComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                } 
                if(writeResultsToNewTableRadio.isSelected()) 
                {
                    writeToTable = writeToNewTableField.getText();
                }

                // Validate the form
                if(writeToTable.isEmpty() | sessionThreshold == null | transitionThreshold.isEmpty() | readFromTable.isEmpty() )
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please double check the input data "
                            + "in the Ping Pong form. Select a radio buttom and/or insert the required data.", "Ping Pong Form Error", 
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }

                // To do...

            }
        });

        // Adding a listener to the refresh JButton
        refreshReadDataFrom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
//                    api.showTables(api.getConnectionSourceServer());
                    String[] items = {"Testing 1", "Testing 2"};
                    api.setCombomBoxNewItemList(items, readFromComboBox);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure you are connected to the server"
                            , "Connection Error", 
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        // Adding a listener to the refresh JButton
        refreshSaveDataTo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    api.showTables(api.getConnectionDestinationServer());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    api.displayErrorBox(ex.getMessage(), "Connection Error!");
                }
            }
        });

        layoutComponents();

        mainFrame.addModuleToLeftPanel("Teste", this);
    }

    public void layoutComponents()
    {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints(); //class that specifies where goes what we want

        ////////// Insert and Align Labels and Fields //////////

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        // Specify to which side it will stick to
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST; // stick to the left hand side

        // how much space it takes relatively to other cells, on the X axis.
        gc.weighty = 2;
        // how much space it takes relatively to other cells, on the Y axis.
        gc.weightx = 8;

        gc.gridx = 0;        
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(readFromLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        add(readFromComboBox, gc);

        gc.gridx = 2;
        add(refreshReadDataFrom, gc);

        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        add(writeResultsToNewTableRadio, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        add(writeToNewTableField, gc);

        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        add(writeResultsToExistingTableRadio, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        add(writeToTableComboBox, gc);

        gc.gridx = 2;
        add(refreshSaveDataTo, gc);

        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        add(accessSessionTimeThresholdLabelLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        add(accessSessionTimeThresholdField, gc);

        gc.gridy = 5;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        add(transitionTimeThresholdLabelLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        add(transitionTimeThresholdField, gc);

        gc.gridy = 6;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        add(smoothLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        add(smoothCheckBox, gc);

        gc.gridy = 7;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        add(statisticsLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        add(statisticsCheckBox, gc);

        gc.weighty = 15;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gc.gridy = 8;
        add(applyButton, gc);
    }



    // Should this method be in the API? I think so...
    private ImageIcon createIcon(String path)
    {
        URL url = getClass().getResource(path);

        if(url == null)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not load the icon: " + path);
        }

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);

        return icon;
    }

}
```

Comment: `leftTabbedPane` is `null` at that point. (And `MainFrame2` is leaking `this` too and causes that problem)

Comment: Without out the ability to test it, I might suggest that `leftTabbedPane` could be `null`.  The `Leaking this` warning is trying to tell you that the instance of the object might not yet be fully initialised and passing to other objects could result in other errors

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but I don't think that passing the frame to your object is a correct practice.

Comment: @MadProgrammer and @zapl I'm initializing leftTabbedPane in my MainFrame class. This way; `private JTabbedPane leftTabbedPane;` and then `leftTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();`

Comment: @StepTNT could you explain me a better approach to this "design problem"?

Comment: Actually I don't know what are you doing in your code because you posted just a little snippet, but I'd rather add the objects to my frame in the frame's constructor. This means that you create you objects and then you add them to the frame, instead of doing the add while you're still creating them. This will help you in decoupling your objects, because now you're creating a dependecy between your frame and the other components

Comment: @dwnz You might like post a little bit more of `MainFrame` as it's impossible to know what's going on...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've edited the question to include full code from both classes.

Comment: Which line is line 213 of MainFrame? `MainFrame2.java:213`

Comment: The leftTabbedPane is initialized AFTER the PingPong constructor is called. So obviously, when this constructor tries to add something to the leftTabbedPane, it's still null.

Comment: @StepTNT I understand and that was my first approach to this problem. But the modules (In this case, PingPong is a module) must be added into the frame from within the module itself. So whoever is creating modules does not need to change and/or add anything in MainFrame class. Or is this approach still not the most suitable? If so please correct me, I'm not expert in this field and I'm still learning and willing to learn more :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels line 213 in `MainFrame2` class is: `leftTabbedPane.add(tittle, module);`

Comment: @JBNizet has just solved my problem! Thank you very much! Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: So, basically, you have two choices.  Either initialise `PingPong` AFTER the `MainFrame` contents have being initialised or provide a means by which `PingPong` can add it's content (or it's content be added to) the `MainFrame` as a separate step

Comment: MadProgrammer and al did all the hard work. They deserve to gain the point.

Comment: "So whoever is creating modules does not need to change and/or add anything in MainFrame class." Why is there `pingPong = new PingPong(api, this);` inside `MainFrame2` then? :) You'll have to edit that class if you want to add modules.

Comment: @zapl Well, that is the only thing they need to add, when I said anything I meant pretty much they don't have to do a lot. And they need `pingPong = new PingPong(api, this)` because the module needs a reference to the api and a reference to the frame. So the module knows where to get the api and where is the frame to add himself (the module). Or am I over complicating this? Or am I forgetting something? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a nice cyclic dependency. A `MainFrame2` needs a `PingPong` which needs a `MainFrame2` again. That's generally something you should avoid because it causes exactly problems like yours. Leaking `this` in the constructor is a good indication that you may have done that. It's not always a problem, especially if the other class just stores the reference for later.

The easy fix in your case should be moving the creation of `PingPong` after that part that initializes the fields that are required.

If you want to get rid of your dependency problem you need to break the cycle. Two options exist: Create `PingPong` without reference to `MainFrame`, then give it to `MainFrame`'s constructor. Or the other way: create `MainFrame` first, then give it to `PingPong`'s constructor.

For a simple implementation you could use a static factory method.

```
class MainFrame2 {

    private MainFrame2() {
        super("An awesome piece of software");
        // etc.. no modules added here
    }

    public static MainFrame2 newInstance() {
        MainFrame2 result = new MainFrame2();

        new PingPong(api, result);
        // alternatively something like:
        // result.addModuleToLeftPanel("Teste", new PingPong(api))

        // add more here

        result.updateTheLayoutBecauseThereAreNewModules();
        return result;
    }
}

class User {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame2 frame = MainFrame2.newInstance();
            // instead of: new MainFrame2();
    }
}
```

Now if you want to solve the problem that adding modules requires changes of `MainFrame2` you can expand the factory pattern to use a registry of modules that adds modules without need to know details about the modules.

```
public class MainFrame2 extends JFrame {

    /** An interface that abstracts creation of a "Module" */
    public interface ModuleFactory {
        public String getTitle();
        public Component createModule(Api api);
    }

    /** A Place to register modules */
    public static enum ModuleRegistry {
        INSTANCE;

        private final List<ModuleFactory> leftModules = new ArrayList<ModuleFactory>();
        public void registerModuleForLeftPanel(ModuleFactory factory) {
            leftModules.add(factory);
        }
        private void addModulesTo(MainFrame2 mainFrame2, Api api) {
            for (ModuleFactory factory : leftModules) {
                mainFrame2.addModuleToLeftPanel(factory.getTitle(), factory.createModule(api));
            }
        }
    }

    /** Creates an instance of MainFrame2 with all registered modules */
    public static MainFrame2 newInstance() {
        MainFrame2 result = new MainFrame2();
        ModuleRegistry.INSTANCE.addModulesTo(result, result.api);
        return result;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Nothing needs to touch `MainFrame2` now. You could distribute it as a library and people could add modules like below.

```
class User {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // static bootstrap code - needs to be run once at the beginning - can be anywhere
        // if you want to add modules you can do it here
        MainFrame2.ModuleRegistry.INSTANCE.registerModuleForLeftPanel(new ModuleFactory() {
            @Override
            public String getTitle() {
                return "Teste";
            }
            @Override
            public Component createModule(Api api) {
                return new PingPong(api);
            }
        });
        // create a mainframe
        MainFrame2.newInstance();
    }
}
```

You could in theory put the registration part into each module (in a `static { }` initializer block) but that causes another problem: The class needs to be loaded in order have a chance to execute code and that's not going to happen if nothing loads that class explicitly.